# Dynamic buttons removing after app relaunches

Tags: java, android, button, dynamic

I've created a button which adds buttons dynamically. It works and when
I click, it adds buttons to activity, but the problem is, when I relaunch the app or open it again, buttons are disappeared. I want those buttons to be permanently. Give the solution. My code is here:

```
 public void onClick(View v)
{

    LinearLayout constrain= findViewById(R.id.constrain);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams ( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Button btn = new Button(second.this);
    btn.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener ( ) {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    } );
    constrain.addView(btn,lp);
}
```

Comment: the issue is that you are not storing the created buttons, so it disappear whaen app closes. Use shared prefernces to store created buttons count and on relaunch fetch the count and recreate the buttons.

Comment: please can you tell how to save buttons in sharedpreferences